# Creating a Power BI duplicate CELL value what if DAX formula

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, powerbi, duplicates, dax

Is there a way in Power BI to write a DAX formula where if there's a duplicate in a column then subtract from another cell?

Example - Customer # 1234567 is listed twice but has a different delivery date. I want to subtract the dates from each other since they are duplicates. The negative would mean it's earlier and the positive means later.

| Customer # |Delivery Date | Difference in Days
| 1234567   | 10/1/2023   |-9 days
| 1234567  | 10/10/2023   |9 days

I searched online and only saw duplicates and eliminating the duplicates. I do not want eliminate the duplicates and the rows are not duplicates. The values in a cell are.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to calculate the difference in days? If you just want to know which date is ealier/ later you can use the rank over the delivery dates:

```
Rank = RANK(DENSE, , ORDERBY('Table'[DeliveryDate], ASC BLANKS LAST), , PARTITIONBY('Table'[OrderID]))
```

[image: Table]